# Transformar coluna dataframe em INT - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Olá

Tenho esse Dataframe, gerado a partir de um arquivo (.txt):

```
    NUMERO_PROCESSO ANO_PROCESSO    TRIBUNAL
0   0010402         2018            18
1   0010758         2014            01
2   0001622         2012            08
3   0020287         2019            04
4   1001446         2018            02
5   0000795         2019            07
6   1001620         2017            02
7   0001006         2019            11
8   0100584         2017            01
9   0010339         2016            18
```

A coluna 'ANO_PROCESSO' é string, como transformo a coluna do DataFrame em INT, ou como resolvo a questão abaixo sem os erros mencionados (gerar um Dataframe com as linhas cujo ANO_PROCESSO seja maior ou igual a 2018):

```
df_remove = df_contas_validas.loc[(int(df_contas_validas['ANO_PROCESSO']) >= 2018)]
```

**erro:** *cannot convert the series to*

```
df_remove = df_contas_validas.loc[(df_contas_validas['ANO_PROCESSO'] >= 2018)]
```

**erro:** *'>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'*

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução, para transformar a coluna STR em INT (dataframe):

```
df_contas_validas['ANO_PROCESSO'] = pd.to_numeric(df_contas_validas['ANO_PROCESSO'])
```

Agora funciona:

```
df_remove = df_contas_validas.loc[(df_contas_validas['ANO_PROCESSO'] >= 2018)]
```

Obrigado.